# How to get information on load from node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want my node.js server to send some data from .json file the load of the page but I keep getting `ReferenceError: socket is not defined`.Is it supposed to use sockets like this?
I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var path = require('path');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var moment = require('moment');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

server.listen(80);
console.log("Server is running!")

app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/publick'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let lastLogs = readFile('public/data/logs.json');
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
    socket.broadcast.emit('savedLogs', lastLogs);
});
function readFile(path) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initiate the socket.io first to emit to a single socket, like this

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.on('myEvent', function (data) {
        socket.emit('myEventResponse','yourResponse');
  });
})
```

But if you want to broadcast to all connected clients you can use just use

```
io.emit('savedLogs', lastLogs);
```